# UITableView doesn't bounce back up to top and is misplaced. iOS 7 issue

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, ios7, uisearchbar

The UITableView doesn't bounce completey back and leaves a white space between the UITableView and the bottom of the nav bar. Also at the top of my tableview is a uisearchbar.
[image]

I tried this but it didn't work

```
[self.view bringSubviewToFront:self.searchBar];
[self.tableView setClipsToBounds:YES];
    if([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue] >= 7.0) {
    CGRect statusBarViewRect = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] statusBarFrame];
    float heightPadding = statusBarViewRect.size.height+self.navigationController.navigationBar.frame.size.height;
    NSLog(@"%f",heightPadding);
    self.tableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(108.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
}
```

Comment: Can you provide some code where you set your UITableView and its SearchBar ?
Did you try without the SearchBar to see if it comes from this ?

Comment: I do everything in the storyboard so don't have code for it. Yes it does the same thing without the search bar.